How to override the default value of an ENV variable in a JestJS Unit Test while testing an exported component?
I am working on a NextJS+React project and need to write a Unit Test using JestJS that depends on one ENV variable. The variables is named to SITE_BRAND and defaulted to brand value.
This is what the test looks like:
import {SignUp} from '@modules/sign-up'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('Sign Up page', () => {
    beforeEach( () => {
        jest.resetModules()
    })

    it('should render sign up form', () => {
        process.env.SITE_BRAND = 'brand1';

        render(<SignUp pageData={pageData} />)
        expect(screen.getByTestId('link-login')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
})

The above expectation does fail if SITE_BRAND !== brand1 which is my issue because the ENV will not change after the component is imported which is my case.
I have Google this and found a few posts: 1, 2, and 3 and following the accepted answer on 1 (updated from (2) to (1)) (this is the first answer on the post) I changed the test to this:
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('Sign Up page', () => {
    beforeEach( () => {
        jest.resetModules()
    })

    it('should render sign up form', () => {
        process.env.SITE_BRAND = 'brand1';
        const SignUp = require('../Signup');

        render(<SignUp pageData={pageData} />)

        expect(screen.getByTestId('link-login')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
})

but the test fails with the following error:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

I also did Google the above issue but could not find anything helpful.
The component is exported as default:
const SignUp = () => { .... }

export default SignUp

How can I use a custom value for the ENV variable and test the component properly?

Have you tried this answer from (2), without the babel plugin? Additionally, if you own the code of SignUp, you could build it in a way that's easier to be unit tested (like accept a property with the site brand that gets populated to the env var by default if not provided - this would make it super easy to test it).

No, I do not own the code :( I do not have the Babel plugin installed, It is answer 1 not 2 my bad

I see. I'd try the answer I linked above without the Babel plugin, it might work.

The issue is that the example is only for a method, while I need to test the entire component. That's why I'm using testing-library and its render method, which is not included in the example.
